# javascript function limiting

Tags: javascript, function, limit

i have a javascript function that creates inputfields for uploading images.

i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add_input(){ 
        var wo = document.getElementById('wo');
        var li = document.createElement('li');

        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'file';
        input.name = 'image[]';

    li.appendChild(input);     
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));

    var button=document.createElement('input');
        button.type = 'button';
        button.className = 'button small';
        button.onclick=function(){delete_input(this);};
        button.value = 'delete';

    li.appendChild(button);
    wo.appendChild(li);
    }

    function delete_input(feld){ 
    feld.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(feld.parentNode);
    }
</script>
```

now my problem is that i would like to create as a maximum 10 inputfields. i never used javascript before and dont know how to limit that.

if there is someone who could tell me how to realize that i would really appreciate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your script so that it will have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var max = 10;
    var current = 0;

    function add_input(){ 
        if(current < max){
            current++;
            //...do everything in here for append
        }
    }

    function delete_input(feld){ 
        if(current > 0){
            current--;
            feld.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(feld.parentNode);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the function, count how many of the items are already there and then leave if there are 10.  I did it here using the 'li', but you can count whatever else is appropriate:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_input(){
    var wo = document.getElementById('wo');
    var objList  = wo.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var soFar = objList.length;
    if (soFar > 9) {
        alert ("yikes");
        return;
    }
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    var input = document.createElement('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to defined a global counter, based on the code you given, here is modification:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;

function add_input(){ 
  if (counter >= 10) 
  return false;
  var wo = document.getElementById('wo');
  var li = document.createElement('li');

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.name = 'image[]';

  li.appendChild(input);     
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));

  var button=document.createElement('input');
  button.type = 'button';
  button.className = 'button small';
  button.onclick=function(){delete_input(this);};
  button.value = 'delete';

  li.appendChild(button);
  wo.appendChild(li);
  counter ++;
}

function delete_input(feld){ 
  feld.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(feld.parentNode);
  counter --;
}

</script>
```